# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \frac{x^{2n}e^{-(\frac{x^2}{2})}}{(2n -1 )!!}dx = c$

Tags: calculus

Need guidance in understanding how to prove the following.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int \frac{x^{2n}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{(2n -1 )!!}dx = c$$ where c is a constant.

It is mentioned in this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.04858.pdf . Page 2, Statement 14.

Here's my attempt. Integrating by parts recursively 3 times gives us.
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[\frac{1}{(2n-1)!!}\left[\frac{x^{2n + 1}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{2n + 1} + \frac{x^{2n + 3}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{(2n + 3)(2n + 1)} + \frac{x^{2n + 5}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}}{(2n + 5)(2n + 3)(2n + 1)} + 
 \int \frac{x^{2n + 6}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{(2n + 5)(2n + 3)(2n + 1)}dx\right]\right]$

This goes on forever. Now not sure if I can start evaluating the limits of individual terms, but if I were to take the limits of each term I think all of the terms except the integral go to zero since (!!) grows faster, I could be wrong. Any simple and intuitive way to see how all these equal a constant "c" ?

Comment: This is an indefinite integral. Are you sure this is the exact problem?

Comment: One of the article I am reading stated that inequality (link in the post above), however there is no proof given. I am trying to understand how it can be proved.

Comment: In terms of the incomplete- and normalised incomplete gamma function, $$
\int^{t} {\frac{{x^{2n} {\rm e}^{ - x^2 /2} }}{{(2n - 1)!!}}{\rm d}x}  = \sqrt \pi  \frac{{2^{n + 1/2} \gamma \left( {n + \frac{1}{2},\frac{{t^2 }}{2}} \right) + C}}{{2^n \Gamma\! \left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)}} \sim \sqrt {2\pi } P\!\left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{{t^2 }}{2}} \right)
 \sim \sqrt {2\pi } \left( {\frac{{t^2 }}{2}} \right)^{n + 1/2} {\rm e}^{ - t^2 /2} \frac{1}{{\Gamma \big( {n + \tfrac{3}{2}} \big)}} \to 0.
$$

Comment: Please write your attempts so your question can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if my solution to it is valid, but maybe just treat it as a way to solve.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int {x^{2n}e^{-x^2\over2}\over(2n+1)!!}dx$$
$$=\int e^{-x^2\over2}\lim_{n\to\infty}{x^{2n}\over(2n+1)!!}dx$$
As the limit diverges for any $x\in\Bbb R$, the integral will be,
$$=\int 0dx$$
ans where equals to
$$0+C=C$$
And it is proven

Extention:For the limit part, I think I have quite a good idea to do so.The limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x^{2n}\over(2n+1)!!}$$
can be rewritten with a new form with products
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\prod_{i=1}^{2n} x\over \prod_{j=0}^{2n} (2n+1-2j)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}{\prod_{i=0}^{2n} x\over x\prod_{j=0}^{2n} (2n+1-2j)}$$
where can be rewritten again with
$$={1\over x}\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{i=0}^{2n} {x\over (2n+1-2i)}$$
or simply
$$={1\over x}\lim_{n\to\infty}{x\over (2n+1)}{x\over (2n-1)}{x\over (2n-3)}...$$
as the term $(2n+1-2i)$ will never be $0$, every term will not approaches ininfity. As there is a zero at the first term, everything must be zero.To show that, it can be written as following(but not really valid, so don't copy that, just for understanding it easier):
$$={1\over x}\lim_{n\to\infty}0{x\over (2n-1)}{x\over (2n-3)}...{x\over 3}x$$
Therfore, we can claim that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{x^{2n}\over(2n+1)!!}=0\quad\forall x\in\Bbb C$$

Comment: Thanks @Isaac Ng. But can you please clarify a bit more when you say that  the limit diverges. The limit evaluation inside the integral sign seems to be 0 so it should converge if I am not wrong.

Comment: @linusk Sorry for explaining it a bit late, you may refer to do with expanding it with products as I mentioned in the post. thx